# Prove that if V is an irreducible representation of a lie algebra, then the dual representation V' must be irreducible.

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

This is an exercise that I am stuck on and any advice on this proof would thus be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried, what are you given?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Suppose that $U$ is an invariant subset of the dual, show that $\{x\in V:u(x)=0,u\in U\}$ is invariant.